# Printing attribute lists in child class

Tags: python, list, class

```
class IceCreamStand(Restaurant):
    """Represents another area of the restuarant businesss"""

    def __init__(self,  restaurant_name, cuisine_type):
        super().__init__(restaurant_name, cuisine_type)

        self.flavors = ['vanilla', 'chocolate', 'strawberry', 'peanut butter']

    def display_flavors(self):
        """displays the type of flavors offered"""

        print("We offer the following flavors at our ice cream shop: ")

        for flavor in flavors:
            print(flavor.title())


myIceCream = IceCreamStand('Nick Ice Cream Shop', 'Custerd')

myIceCream.display_flavors()
```

I am trying to print out the list of flavors in the method display_flavors(self) can't seem to get it to work. I believe there is an issue with the for loop not recognizing that flavors is defined above...

Any help?

Comment: `for flavor in self.flavors`

Comment: lol.... thank you it worked. simple mistakes.